# How to override built-in asp.net javascripts provided by WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net

I need to change the `WebForm_AutoFocus()` function generated by ASP.Net. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Why did you close my question without any asking for clarifications? This question is very important for me. I was about to set a bounty on it. As far as I'm concerned, it is clear and helpful. ASP.NET generates javascript functions. I need to know how to override them.

Comment: I vote for reopening. I don't know how to override this script but the question is legit. Or at least desevers a comment about closing.

Comment: @Sly:  This question was closed by a moderator, who only needs one vote to close questions instead of the normal 5.  Since it was a moderator, this question was probably flagged.

Comment: I did not flag this question, but it is pretty borderline.  It seems to be a legitimate question, but you don't appear to have done any research on your own to answer it before coming to StakOverflow with it.  [StackOverflow isn't a research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553), and we ask that you research the problem on your own before posting here.

Comment: I did research before posting here. The question is short because there is not much more to say.

Comment: If you did any form of research, you need to show us what you found. Even if we were to assume you did any research, it's not much use if we don't see it.

Comment: @BoltClock: I found a hack to override the built-in function: Microsoft decided to make the `WebForm_AutoFocus` a global function.  So I used the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to register a script that runs after and that replaces the global function with my own version. It is a hack but so far it is the only solution I have.